# onclick event input button does not fire on IE 11

Tags: jquery, onclick, attr, internet-explorer-11

I have input elements of type button created using jquery function. These buttons are added dynamically via script that fire on image load. The info on the buttons is read from metadata that is available as a object on the DOM.

When I click on these elements, these do not fire (or not action happens) on IE11. It works fine on FF27.

DOM explorer (example below) shows the onclick attribute is set fine for these elements (since it working on FF).

jquery used to build the input buttons (done in a loop, fired on image onload)

```
$(input).attr({
    'type': 'button',
    'id': mytds.id,
    'value': mytds.text,
    'class': 'sbarButton',
    'cmd': mytds.cmd,
    'option': mytds.option,
    'form': mytds.form,
    'args': mytds.args,
    'arg2': mytds.arg2,
    'qual': mytds.qual,
    'scope': mytds.scope,
    'IX': mytds.IX,
    'IY': mytds.IY,
    'IZ': mytds.IZ,
    'forward': mytds.forward,
    'onclick':'clicked()'
});
```

function clicked() { alert ("Clicked:"); }

I have tried to reassign the click attribute using other options to see if it will work on IE, for e.g.

$(input)[0].setAttribute('onclick','clicked()');

It doesn't throw any script error, pretty much does nothing on click on these buttons.

Help is appreciated to find out what's going on & correct the situation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zmAjx/

Comment: @DaveMethvin These buttons are added dynamically as a part of loading a div content (async) by reading a javascript object which is filled from some meta-data. to achieve this, I have am image on the div, which has a onload script (the same above) which adds these buttons on the DOM.

Use Case: different divs swap in & out based upon user interaction & I need to put buttons/options based upon user selection (options configured in meta-data).

if this not a good approach, what is your recommendation. To reiterate, the problem happens on IE, not on FF.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: @NiravVira, I'm not Dave, but I agree - not a good idea to use onclick attributes. Instead, you should look into event eelegation. Find the closest shared `parent` element, and delegate the click event to that. Something like: `$('#parentToInputs').on('click', '.common', handler)`

Comment: Here's a fiddle using event delegation and dynamic elements: http://jsfiddle.net/76HDW/

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. Thank you for the post. I was able to use the delegate approach & get my task in hand done.